# How to improve performance of keplergl?

Tags: kepler.gl

Is there a way to improve the performance of keplergl by deactivate some features not required in the use-case?

Ideas:

1. Remove the side bar (not just hiding but that it's not loaded at all)
2. Disable object interactivity (hover/click effects) on high zoom levels
3. Only load objects in the current viewport (+ some space around it)

Comment: Maybe the "aggregation on the fly" feature could be combined with the zoom level which might at least improve "performance" on high zoom levels

Comment: I scanned the open issues on github: The following planned features could improve performance issues described here: https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl/issues/329, https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl/issues/328. It also seems not yet possible to query the viewport: https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl/issues/197?

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution:

- use the Grid-based aggregation for higher zoom levels

This improved the performance when displaying the data set linked in the question from "almost frozen" on the highest zoom level to "slightly laggy".

[image]

**I'm not sure, however, how to subscribe to the view port zoom level changes.**